# Require a module relative to the original code

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have this directory structure:

```
project/
  mymodule.js
  test/
    run.js
    node_modules/
      canvas/
```

I have code like so:

**run.js**

```js
var Canvas = require(__dirname+"/../mymodule");
```

**mymodule.js**

```js
if (typeof require==='function' && typeof module==='object'){
  // when using mymodule with Node the 'canvas' module must be available
  var canvas = require('canvas');
  module.exports = canvas;
} else {
  // code that works in a web browser, without Node
}
```

The result of `node test/run.js` is `Error: Cannot find module 'canvas'`.

How can I make it so that the `require` from `mymodule` knows to look relative to the original script? Or is that contrary to the way Node modules work? Must I move `canvas` (which is only used for testing on my end) out of the `test` directory?

Answer (score 0):

When you don't put a path in the require statement, it assumes you're trying to load a module. If you want to load something in your code, be sure to include a relative or absolute path. In your case:

```
  var canvas = require('./test/node_modules/canvas');
```

The other way to do this is to have your node_modules directory in root, and not web-accessible.

```
project/
  mymodule.js
  node_modules/
     canvas/  
  test/
    run.js
```

Then in your run.js or your mymodule.js you can `require('canvas')` as you'd expect.

Comment: Your first suggestion would work, but would work only for me, not users of my module who will have a 'normal' module structure. The second is the last sentence of my question (which, if this is truly the only way, is what I suppose I must do).